# How do I traverse a numpy matrix row by row?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a numpy array

```
[[ 0 -2 -4 -6]
 [-2 -3 -5 -7]
 [-4  0 -2 -4]
 [-6 -2 -3 -5]]
```

How do I visit each of the elements of this numpy array known as mymatrix, **row by row** such that `mymatrix[x][y]=the element that is traversed`, so for instance I would get `0,-2,-4,-6,-2,-3,-5,-7,-4,0,-2,-4,-6,-2` and so on if the **array** is traversed through a double for loop

EDIT:

When I follow the double for loop method from below, this is what I get

```
for row in range(scorematrix.shape[0]):
    for col in range(scorematrix.shape[1]):
        final=[]
        if row==0 and col==0:
            scorematrix[row][col]=0
            continue
        elif row==0:
            scorematrix[row][col]=col+(col*-3)
            continue
        elif col==0:
            scorematrix[row][col]=row+(row*-3)
            continue
        elif seq1[row]=="A" and seq2[col]=="A":
            result=4
        elif seq1[row]=="C" and seq2[col]=="C":
            result=3
        elif seq1[row]=="G" and seq2[col]=="G":
            result=2
        elif seq1[row]=="T" and seq2[col]=="T":
            result=1
        elif seq1[row]!=seq2[col]:
            result=-3
        print(scorematrix)
        firstelement=result+scorematrix[row-1,col-1]
        final.append(firstelement)
        secondelement=scorematrix[row-1,col]-2
        final.append(secondelement)
        thirdelement=scorematrix[row,col-1]-2
        final.append(thirdelement)
        themax=max(final)
        index=[k for k, j in enumerate(final) if j == themax]
        listofc.append(index)

        scorematrix[row][col]=themax
```

the main bits necessary for my question is the first two lines and the last line, the rest is just some calculations.
The matrix I want to output is `[[ 0 -2 -4 -6]
                                      [-2 -3 -5 -7]
                                      [-4  0 -2 -4]
                                      [-6 -2 -3 -5]]`

But the matrix that I get is

`[[ 0 -2 -4 -6]
 [-2 -3  0 -2]
 [-4 -5 -2 -3]
 [-6 -7 -4 -5]]`
If you ignore the rows and columns with `0,-2,-4,-6`, you can see that what SHOULD be the first row has been entered as the first column and so on.

How do I correct this?

Comment: `mymatrix[x]` doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `for element in mymatrix.ravel()`.

Comment: What are you going to do with each 'visit'?  Just print it?  change it?  `A.ravel()` or `for item in A.ravel(): print(item)` is simpler than a double loop.  Not faster, just simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've updated my question to show you what exactly I'm asking for

Comment: Does anything change if you use `scorematrix[row, col] = themax` instead? The separate subscripting can do unexpected things when you use slices, but I have no idea why it wouldn't work here.

Comment: Yep just tried that, I get an incorrect output

Comment: Have you tried simply switching the `col` and `row` in the two `for` loop declarations?

Comment: Yeah, and no change